# Unable to copy files (.pdf/.jpeg/.jpg) from one folder to another

Tags: excel, vba, search

Using 2010 Excel VBA - I need to use look up the image/pdf with the **Branch Code** as a part of its name at "C:\ECB Test\ECB IR COPY" and paste it at "C:\ECB Test\" RO if it exists. If it doesn't, the program needs to highlight the Branch Code.

(File Name Examples: 28-Kochi-ecb-sdwan completed.pdf, 23 eCB Kozhikode completed.pdf/0036.jpeg)

Having done this manually twice for two other excel sheets (4k+ cells), I decided to Frankenstein a module together and, well, it does not work and I have no idea why.

[image]

```
Sub Sort()

    Const SRC_PATH As String = "C:\ECB Test\ECB IR COPY"
    Const DEST_PATH As String = "C:\ECB Test"
    
    Dim Row_Number As Integer
    Dim fso As Object
    Set fso = VBA.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Dim Folder_Name As String
    Dim Branch_Code As String
    Dim Final_Path As Variant
    Dim File As String

        For Row_Number = 3 To 2465
        
            Branch_Code = Worksheets("WAN RFP").Cells(Row_Number, 2)
            Folder_Name = Worksheets("WAN RFP").Cells(Row_Number, 5)
            
            On Error Resume Next
    
            File = Dir(SRC_PATH & "\*" & Branch_Code & "*")
            Final_Path = Dir(DEST_PATH & "\" & Folder_Name & "\")
            
            If (Len(File) > 0) Then
                Call fso.CopyFile(File, Final_Path)
            Else
            Cells(Row_Number, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
            End If
            On Error GoTo 0

            DoEvents
        Next Row_Number

End Sub
```

I think its unable to use the Branch Code variable as a wildcard, though I might as well have done something silly somewhere in the code. Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using the destination path instead of the source path:

```
File = Dir(DEST_PATH & "*" & Branch_Code & "*.*")
```

Change it to

```
File = Dir(SRC_PATH & "*" & Branch_Code & "*.*")
```

Comment: It still doesn't work... I made a few changes to the code

Comment: nvm i made a few more dumb mistakes, its working now. Thank you so much dude!

I needed to use ```Call fso.CopyFile(SRC_PATH & "\" File, Final_Path)``` instead of ```Call fso.CopyFile(File, Final_Path)```